# Records without email addresses get stuck in the email activity and don't stuck in the sms activity when not having a phone number provided

Tags: marketing-cloud, journeybuilder

Does anyone know, how is it possible that a record without an email address will fail to pass an email activity in the journey in Marketing Cloud and a record without a phone number will success to pass an SMS activity?

Comment: What channel addresses are configured in your journey settings?